# Laravel 5 DomPdf render error

Tags: html, laravel-5, dompdf

using DomPdf to create PDF from html.

```
$html = '<html><head><body>Test</body></head></html>
$pdf = \App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
$pdf->loadHTML($html);
$pdf->render();
return $pdf->stream();
```

Get error:

```
Call to protected method Barryvdh\DomPDF\PDF::render() from context 'App\Http\Controllers\TestController'
```

When remove "

```
$pdf->render();
```

Create PDF file,but mess html code...

Tnx, P

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you're using https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf?

You're receiving the error because you're trying to call a protected method from your controller.

The docs say you can do the following:

> You can save it to a file, or stream (show in browser) or download.

```
$pdf->save('myfile.pdf')
$pdf->stream();
$pdf->download('invoice.pdf');
```